# setting some checkbox to true by default for a custom ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, checkbox, android-arrayadapter

I am working on an Android app right now that will put shortcuts of apps onto the home screen.

I have everything working fine right now.

Currently the user is presented with a list of applications that are installed and they can multi select from the list with `CheckBox`'s. **However, I would like my application to already have some of the applications in the list checked by default when the user launches the app.**

For instance, when the user first launches the application there are 3 of the apps that are selected by default ( for what ever reason, can be hard coded or in a properties file this does not matter right now ).

How can i do this? I basically need to be able to compare the name of the scanned application against a name in a properties file and if they match, check it by default. I have tried a couple ways and am lost. Can someone point me in the right direction or give me some hints here?

**Getting the reference to the `CheckBox` associated with an item in the list from the custom `ArrayAdapter` seems to be my issue.**

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to basically create a class that would contain the information regarding the shortcuts. And in the class it had a boolean for holding on to the state of the selection of the checkbox. Basiclly using a MVC pattern.

Then i updated my `getView()` in my adapter. And added a method in my main activity for setting the default selected. Then added a method in my adapter to set the checked shortcuts and `notifyDataSetChanged()` everytime a change was made.

If anyone would like more detail, just comment here and i can add code if needed.

Comment: I will work on putting together the example, will post as soon as possible.